# Extract model coefficients from `finalfit` table

Tags: r

Short version: Is it possible (aside from reverse processing the formatted cell contents) to extract the coefficients from a table reporting the results of regression models generated using the `finalfit` package?

Background: Using the (amazing) `finalfit` package I can produce tables of results from regression models. I want to report some of these same results in the text of an Rmarkdown document. I do not want to run the regression models twice, once in `finalfit` for the tables and once to generate output to be used in text. Also, `finalfit` processes the coefficients (e.g. exponentiates coefficients from logistic regression models to generate odds ratios, consistently formats decimal points) and I do not want to duplicate these steps.

This code below produces a formatted table of results from a logistic regression model (note: deliberately using base R code for model):

```
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
explanatory = c("age", "sex.factor")
dependent = "mort_5yr"
colon_s %>%
  ## Crosstable
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, fit_id=TRUE)  %>% 
  ff_merge(
    glm(
      mort_5yr ~ age + sex.factor, family="binomial", data = colon_s
    ) %>% 
  fit2df(estimate_suffix=" (multivariable)")
  ) %>% 
  select(-c(fit_id, index)) %>% 
  dependent_label(colon_s, dependent)
```

I cannot see how I can extract the odds ratio for Sex:Male from this table (or the pipeline to produce it), without running and processing the `glm` model separately.

Extracting the cell contents directly (as suggested by @LyzandeR) results in this string: "0.98 (0.76-1.27, p=0.888)"
The relevant coefficients, confidence intervals and P-value would need to be extracted. This nearly achieves the result, but  is not ideal given that they have all previously been calculated and concatentated into this string.

Note: I am happy to achieve the desired result using a different package.

Comment: If I understand correctly you can add `%>%
  select("OR (multivariable)") %>% slice(3)`

Comment: The `finalfit` package processes the coefficients and adds in brackets etc to make the table look nice. If I process cells from the formatted table I will then need to strip off the formatting again, which is relatively easy to do but seems a bit cumbersome and not generalisable to other regression models or cell contents (ie. the summary columns in the above example).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest in this package.

It's a good thought and not something we have implemented as you describe. You can use the internal functions (which are exported) to do this.

Not that pretty but will give you a table of coefficients, 95% CI and p-values in your pipeline.

```
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
explanatory = c("age", "sex.factor")
dependent = "mort_5yr"
colon_s %>%
    summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, fit_id=TRUE)  %>% 
    ff_merge(
        glmmulti(colon_s, dependent, explanatory)[[1]] %>%  # glmmulti/glm etc. will work
            extract_fit() %>% 
            {coef_table <<- .} %>%  # save an extra table in the pipeline
            condense_fit(estimate_suffix = " (multivariable)") %>% 
            remove_intercept()
    ) %>% 
    select(-c(fit_id, index)) %>% 
    dependent_label(colon_s, dependent)
```

Just in case you hadn't see it, the bare models without formatting can be generated thus:

```
explanatory = c("age", "sex.factor")
dependent = "mort_5yr"
colon_s %>% 
    finalfit(dependent, explanatory, condense = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks - this pretty much does it, but I've tweaked it for my preference in an additional answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking @Ewen answer for my own preferences:

```
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
explanatory = c("age", "sex.factor")
dependent = "mort_5yr"
colon_s %>%
  ## Crosstable
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, fit_id=TRUE)  %>% 
  ff_merge(
    glm(
      mort_5yr ~ age + sex.factor, family="binomial", data = colon_s
    ) %>% 
      fit2df(condense = FALSE) %>%  
      {coef_multi <<- .} %>% # generate a table of raw coefficients here
      condense_fit(estimate_suffix=" (multivariable)")
  ) %>% 
  select(-c(fit_id, index)) %>% 
  dependent_label(colon_s, dependent)
```

Note: this approach can also be used for the coefficients from univariate models

The only sticking point is getting the raw summary stats, but really that's not tricky!

Comment: The stats (means, medians etc.) from `summary_factorlist`